# ghc issue with hmatrix

Tags: haskell, gsl

I'm trying to use `hmatrix`, and `hmatrix-gsl-stats`.  But I am getting absolutely bizarre results.  Can anybody reproduce what I'm seeing?

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import Numeric.GSL.Fitting.Linear

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let y = fromList [1,2,3,4,5]
  let x = trans $ fromLists [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,1,1,1,1]]
  let x3 = fromLists [[1,1], [2,1], [3,1], [4,1], [5,1]]
  print $ x == x3
  print $ multifit x y
  print $ multifit x3 y
```

So I just compile this and run it, and I get:

```
True
(fromList [0.6121951219512196,0.39756097560975645],(2><2)
 [   0.5100317271465397, -0.46568114217727535
 , -0.46568114217727535,     0.82048582193139 ],27.27560975609756)
(fromList [1.0000000000000002,-8.881784197001252e-16],(2><2)
 [ 2.1364982849735737e-32, -6.40949485492072e-32
 ,  -6.40949485492072e-32, 2.350148113470931e-31 ],6.409494854920721e-31)
```

Am I missing something totally obvious?

Comment: What happens if you print `x` and `x3`? I'm wondering if they have the same values, but different dimensions. (I would expect `==` to catch that, though.)

Comment: Yeah, they look completely identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a problem with how matrix transposition is handled internally. When you call `trans`, it's just a flipped bit in the metadata... that is apparently *not* being inspected when passing the matrix through the FFI.

If you try this, `multifit (reshape (cols x) $ flatten x) y`, on your penultimate line, you can force the transposition.

Comment: That sounds like a fairly serious bug to me. Should Victor complain to the author of the bindings or the author of the underlying library?

Comment: Yeah, `multifit (reshape (cols x) $ flatten x) y` does it right.  But I'm wondering if anybody managed to reproduce this?

Comment: I could reproduce the issue, and I agree that it's a pretty serious bug. Perhaps using `cmat` instead of `mat` in the [definition](https://github.com/amcphail/hmatrix-gsl-stats/blob/master/lib/Numeric/GSL/Fitting/Linear.hs#L137) of `multifit` would be sufficient, but this issue is likely more widespread.

Comment: Ok thanks!  While we're at it, I guess it's likely to be a bug in the `hmatrix-gsl-stats` module rather  than the 'hmatrix` module?  I ran the tests in `hmatrix-tests` and that seems to run fine.

Comment: The documentation in `Data.Packed.Internal.Matrix` of the `hmatrix` package seems to suggest that it is up to the programmer to ensure the matrix is in the desired transposition state (using `cmat` and `fmat`).  (I'm the author of `hmatrix-gsl-stats`).

Comment: Arg, `cmat` and `fmat` are not exposed.

Comment: `cmat` and `fmat` can be found in `Data.Packed.Development` and `let x = cmat $ trans $ fromLists [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,1,1,1,1]]` works.

Comment: The package `hmatrix-gsl-stats` has been upgraded to fix this bug.